# PyQt4 can't import Qsci

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt, qscintilla

I'm installing PyQt4 on an old Linux system (CentOS 4.4) that can't be upgraded for hardware compatibility reasons. I've got Python 2.6, QT4 and SIP installed, and the installation of PyQt4 didn't give me any errors.

When I run Python, this happens:

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, May 11 2011, 14:18:37) 
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
>>> import PyQt4.Qsci
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Qsci
```

I looked around, and found `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/qscintilla.py`, which is almost empty of non-comment stuff:

```
pluginType = MODULE

def moduleInformation():
    return "PyQt4.Qsci", ("QsciScintilla", )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install [qscintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/QScintilla2/index.html) separately.  If PyQt is already installed, then you should just have to install the qscintilla python bindings.  Hopefully this fixes your issue!

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't have a download link, the source for [QScintilla2 can be downloaded here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/download)

Comment: In ubuntu is this package: libqscintilla2-dev

Comment: thanks @dbr ! and here is how to install it http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/